# Word "Complicated"

Tags: expressions

When you say a place is "complicated", what does it mean?

When I hear the word "complicated" I think of problem that is hard to solve,
a place like maze, situation that requires lots of explanations.

But I see some people use word "complicated" to describe a place that is
so crowded and chaotic.

For example, somebody said a library was so complicated because of too many visitors, and I thought it sounded awkward

Can word "complicated" also be used as adjectives like chaotic?

Comment: You should add some example questions to describe the usages you intend.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to include details in your posts, like the example you gave. Do not use the comments for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! 'Complicated' **does** mean that [it is difficult to understand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complicated).
That said, we can have a complicated problem, puzzle, sum, and so on. I've never come across *complicated place* to mean *crowded.*

But yes, it can mean chaotic (but then 'chaotic' is again difficult to tackle/understand). Thus, many authors call our 'world,' [a *complicated place.*](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/david_remnick_434711)

Comment: Our world is a complicated place because of many troubles and problems associated with it right? Thank you as always!